# node.js Synchronous version of http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, testing

I want to write a tester that will test a http server I wrote for class.
and I need a synchronous version of http.get/http.post

I wanted to make an object with a "test" method that will return true or false if the test passed but found no way to get the code to wait until the server responds to the get request.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: Any wait period smaller than .75 of a second will seem synchronous to a human.  Just set the timeout to a small (but large enough) value.

Comment: How can I make the program to wait? Set timeout doesn't work

Comment: You say your using node.js, this is how it works, it waits on communication auto-magically.  Please post the code you are having a question with then maybe your question will have an answer.

Comment: Yea, I got it work eventually. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with Node.js without horrible, busy-waiting hacks.  Make your `test` method asynchronous as well, calling a callback parameter to deliver the results of the test back to the caller.  Or use a different language for your unit testing.